# can't find AppDelegate icon in MainWindow.xib in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, xcode3.2

I've created project using empty template in xcode 4.2 but i couldn't find App delegate icon in MainWindow.xib and so i'm not able to connect it to root view controller icon.
When i tried to open the same project in xcode 3.2.3  i can see app delegate with name MyProjectNameAppDelegte but in xcode 4.2 name is just AppDelegate.Why so?.Also even if i try to open MainWindow.xib in xcode 3.2.3 it's not launching interface builder,instead it's launching xcode 4.2 and there i can see either App Delegate icon(if launched through xcode 3.2.3.) or Switch View Controller icon(if launched within xcode 4.2).

Answer (score 0):

Short Version:

-[Specify default xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219907/how-does-xcode-decide-which-xib-to-load-first-how-can-i-change-that)

-[Configure app delegate in Xib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874822/how-to-hook-up-the-window-of-mainwindow-xib-with-the-appdelegate-in-xcode-4-2)

In more detail:

I don't know why XCode 3.x is different, but if you are asking how to view and establish connections between your app delegate, main window, and root view controller, then this has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874822/how-to-hook-up-the-window-of-mainwindow-xib-with-the-appdelegate-in-xcode-4-2).

In addition, if you just created a project, it may not be set to load from the Xib at all.  When I just created a "Single Page" project, it generated code to programmatically create a window from the empty Xib file also generated by XCode.  If you want to load from the "pickled" Xib file instead of doing so programatically, you will need to follow the instructions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219907/how-does-xcode-decide-which-xib-to-load-first-how-can-i-change-that).