# How does Xcode decide which xib to load first? How can I change that?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xib

I have downloaded an Xcode project that has three xibs (A.xib, B.xib, and C.xib). I noticed that:

- None of them is called "MainWindow.xib".
- In the project summary the **Main Interface** value is set to **MainWindow**
- **Main nib file base name** is not set
- **Main.c** does not specify the app delegate either `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

Still, when I build&run, the app loads A.xib.
How does the app decide what to load?

I am using Xcode 4 and I am targeting iOS 5.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `Main Interface` in the Summary tab of your app target.

See this image:

[image: Main Interface]

EDIT: Or, as Alan wrote, you can set it in your info.plist file.

EDIT 2: Oh. I see what your problem is. You can use MainWindow as your main .xib file, but you have to edit which .xib is loaded in MainWindow. Open MainWindow.xib, and select the view controller that is used. If I'm right, its class is set to `A`. If you want B.xib to be used, you have to change the class to `B`. You will also have to set the NIB being used for the view controller, in the Attribute Inspector.

Set the class for the UIViewController being used in MainWindow.xib:

[image: Set the class]

Set the NIB:

[image: Set the NIB]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but I get a crash. `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x6c90160> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1df5052 0x1c15d0a 0x1df4f11 0x364032 0x2d5f7b 0x2d5eeb 0x2f0d60 0x83291a 0x1df6e1a 0x1d60821 0x83146e 0x833010 0x61314a 0x613461 0x6127c0 0x621743 0x6221f8 0x615aa9 0x20a3fa9 0x1dc91c5 0x1d2e022 0x1d2c90a 0x1d2bdb4 0x1d2bccb 0x6122a7 0x613a9b 0x1dcd 0x1d45)
terminate called throwing an exception`. Do you know why?

Comment: The xib you've set does not have a UIWindow (or hasn't linked the outlet to the UIWindow in it). Every app must have one linked UIWindow in the main xib.

Comment: I've added a UIWindow to the xib, added an IBOutlet in the AppDelegate.h, and connected things in IB... but I still get this `-[UIApplication _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c59770
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c59770'
*** First throw call stack:...
terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried as suggested in Edit #2 but I get " Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch". Apparently didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is never called but I am not entirely sure why.

Comment: Remember to change the class being used in the app delegate as well. But could you give a link to the project you have downloaded? It will be a lot easier to test this having the project myself.

Comment: I made a mistake (created a new MainWindow.xib instead of using the existing one -which was very well hidden in a group!). Now I understand how the xib is chosen. Changing the class and the NIB name is still giving me this though `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MTViewController 0x6cdc200> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window.'
*** First throw call stack:...
terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: This is the project I am working on. My classes are the ones starting with MT (plus the CircleD class). http://dl.dropbox.com/u/369957/JabberClient.zip I will post the link to the original project in a second.

Comment: I don't know why you get that last error. I tried doing this myself. I created a new project, added a new class (subclass of UIViewController) with a xib, changed the class of the UIViewController in MainWindow.xib and the NIB Name. And then it worked as expected; it loaded the new xib in MainWindow.

Comment: This is the link to the original project http://dl.dropbox.com/u/369957/jabber-tutorial-fixed.zip   Have you by chance tried to do the same on my project?

Comment: I don't know which xib you want to change it to, but if you want to change it to `SMLoginViewController`, you can do this: Open MainWindow.xib, select the UIViewController, change the class in the Identity Inspector to `SMLoginViewController`, change the NIB Name in the Attributes Inspector to `SMLoginViewController`. That's it. I used the original project, by the way.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I've tried with MTViewController. I've fixed the "NSUnknownKeyException" that I was experiencing before by adding `@synthesize window` in the view controller. Now I get `Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`. There might be something wrong since I added the UIWindow.

Answer (score 0):

In your application's Info.plist.

Comment: Do you mean the "Main nib file base name" entry?

Comment: Well it's the same setting as the one matsr showed you, so just change it there. But read the comment I wrote underneath.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more question: what if this value is not set? Does Xcode look for classes that are subclasses of ` NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>`?

Comment: Well, every app needs to have one App delegate, and one UIWindow. The link between project -> App delegate is through the root xib, and the link from App delegate -> UI window is through the root xib as well. Create a new project from scratch and open its MainWindow.xib. You'll notice there's a 'Appname App Delegate' object in the xib; make sure your custom xib replicates the same structure.