# How to hook up the window of MainWindow.xib with the AppDelegate in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am experimenting with Interface Builder in Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 on a old Mac.

In Xcode 3.2 there was always a MainWindow.xib file and it contained not only the File's Owner which was UIApplication IMHO, but also an App Delegate placeholder object.

I created a MainWindow.xib file using the Window xib template. The AppDelegate placeholder is missing, so I can't hook the window up to my actual app delegate object.

I suppose that I will need to add a placeholder object with it's class identity set to "AppDelegate" but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag out one of the blue cubes (called "Object") from the objects library and change its class to the class of your app delegate.

Comment: They're orange. But I figured out using a normal Object instead of a Placeholder object worked. Although it makes no sense.